# Create random list of strings in random size in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data in my excel.

```
A
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4
Text 5
Text 6
```

I want to fill column `B` with random joined data from column `A`. It should respect the criteria `1> B > 6`. i.e. Column `B` should have a min 1 value from column `A` or can have a max of up to 6 unique values joined by `,`. I can have column `B` dragged up to 100 rows. But still, they should respect the criteria.

I'm able to get a random value from column `A` using the formula `INDEX($A$1:$A$6, RANDBETWEEN(1, ROWS($A$1:$A$6)), 1)`, and to join 2 random texts I'm using the formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",true, INDEX($A$1:$A$6, RANDBETWEEN(1, ROWS($A$1:$A$6)), 1), INDEX($A$1:$A$6, RANDBETWEEN(1, ROWS($A$1:$A$6)), 1))
```

Currently, I'm able to get 2 fixed strings using this formula. Instead of doing the above 6 times, I want to know If there is a way to get this joined string with a random number of unique strings(of the max size of column A length concatenated with a `,`).

I'm able to get only 1 value using the random function. Please let me know how can I do this.

Comment: Please include your own attempt for debugging purposes

Comment: Hey @JvdV, I've updated my question with what I've tried.

Comment: "get this joined string with a random number of unique strings (of the max size of column A length" - by this, did you mean that if you add a 7th value to column A, you're expecting up to 7 possible concatenated strings rather than 6?

Comment: You will have duplicates with 6 values and 100 rows as there are only 63 unique strings that can be created.

Comment: Similar... https://superuser.com/questions/1651447/generating-dummy-text-in-excel-table/1651560#1651560

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,TAKE(SORTBY(A1:A6,RANDARRAY(COUNTA(A1:A6))),RANDBETWEEN(1,6)))
```

---

Note that `TAKE()` is a new function which is still in BETA. If you don't have access just yet, then try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,INDEX(SORTBY(A1:A6,RANDARRAY(COUNTA(A1:A6))),SEQUENCE(RANDBETWEEN(1,6))))
```

---

In each option:

- `SORTBY(A1:A6,RANDARRAY(COUNTA(A1:A6)))` - Will create a randomized array of the values in column A;
- `RANDBETWEEN(1,6)` - The part which defines the lower- & upper-limit of strings to concatenate;
- `TAKE/INDEX` - A way to retrieve an X amount of rows from the above randomized array. In your case X itself is randomized (see 2nd bullit);
- `TEXTJOIN()` - Concatenate all selected values into a single string.

Answer (score 2):

This formula exploits the functions `RANDARRAY` and `RANDBETWEEN` to get a random number of text items to join.

First, I created a dynamic named range called `AllTextItems`. This automatically expands to capture any number of rows in your dataset:

[image]

Then, use the formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(AllTextItems,RANDARRAY(RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(AllTextItems)),1,1,ROWS(AllTextItems),TRUE)))
```

in the cells you'd like your joined list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, INDEX(A:A, RANDARRAY(1, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTA(A:A)), 1, COUNTA(A:A), TRUE)))
```

EDIT didn't quite beat JvdV to it, but basically a similar basis to his but not using `TAKE` and not sorting the output